# How to deal with the error "The request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data"?

Tags: jquery, servlets

I am working on a web application that consists of only 1 servlet. The type of page requested is determined based on a get parameter that is sent in the request. I am having a problem when trying to upload images to the server. I am sending an AJAX post request using jquery with the image file and other data I need to send appended to a FormData object. I have read that I need to use the HttpServletRequest getParts or getPart methods to extract the file and other data. My problem is that if I set the @MultipartConfig annotation in my servet class, I get an error "The request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data..etc" whenever I send a request since only one specific page will upload files to the server and the rest will not. Is there any way for me to use the getParts method in my existing servlet without creating a new servlet just for file uploads?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible.

But fortunately, Java is an object oriented language. It supports composition and inheritance. With inheritance, you can just extend an existing non-`@MultipartConfig` servlet into a new class with `@MultipartConfig` annotation and put code there which deals specifically with uploaded file, and then calls the inherited methods for the existing remainder.

In other words, just create a new servlet, [but reuse code instead of copypasting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks for your help BalusC. That seems to be the optimal solution.